# php single dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to output an array containing events which is ical file output to be precise.
Array in itself looks as below:

```
  Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [UID] => 4C2DDB6E-5B5B-4B97-BEBE-FF424BB154F8
        [DTEND] => 20131116 [SUMMARY] => test1_ONS
        [LAST-MODIFIED] => 20131111T210530Z
        [DTSTAMP] => 20131111T213437Z
        [DTSTART] => 20131112
        [LOCATION] => City
        [SEQUENCE] => 1
        [DESCRIPTION] => description here_http://www.test.com/test1
        [SUMMARY] => some text here
) )
```

I'm able to loop trough its records and output all events using the following foreach loop:

```
    foreach ($events_sorted as $event) {
$client = current(explode("_", $event['SUMMARY']));
} and so on...
```

The tricky part is that my table layout for events is based on months and looks as follows:

```
             CLIENT   EXHIBITION   CITY
_________________________________________
OCT 2013     client   exhibition   city
             client   exhibition   city
             client   exhibition   city
________________________________________
NOV 2013     client   exhibition   city
             client   exhibition   city
________________________________________
DEC 2013     client   exhibition   city
```

What I'm unable to do is to loop trough all the events, output their corresponding month name **once** as per layout, output their data for the corresponding events and proceed to the next month.

My table layout however is built the way that its its first row contains month name data and has to be somehow distinguished from all other rows containing events:

```
<table id="table_events">
                <tbody><tr id="header_row">
                <th id="date_header"></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr class="month_start">
                <td>
                <div class="month_rect">
                    <div class="month_rect_text month_long">SEPT</div>
                    <div class="month_rect_year">2013</div>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>eee</td>
                <td>eee</td>
                <td>Oslo</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>
                    </td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="oct" class="month_start">
                <td>
                <div class="month_rect">
                    <div class="month_rect_text month_short">OCT</div>
                    <div class="month_rect_year">2013</div>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    </td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="month_start">
                <td>
                <div class="month_rect">
                    <div class="month_rect_text month_short">NOV</div>
                    <div class="month_rect_year">2013</div>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>
                    </td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                </tr>

                </tbody></table>
```

Until now I also tried creating new array based on months but with no luck either:

```
 foreach($events_sorted as $test) {
$month_number = gmdate("m", $ical->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($test['DTSTART']));

$r = array("month" => $month_number);

}
```

My last idea was to print out all events and by resetting array check for existence of month name, if it exists then do not output it again and use different table row layout but I'm unsure how to implement this solution. I hope there is easier way to achieve described effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"></td>
      <td>CLIENT</td>
      <td>EXHIBITION</td>
      <td>CITY</td>
    </tr>
    <?php $last_event = NULL; ?>
    <?php foreach($events as $event) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php if($last_event != NULL) : if($last_event['DATE'] != $event['DATE']) : echo $event['DATE']; endif; else : echo $event['DATE']; endif; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $event['CLIENT']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $event['EXHIBITION']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $event['CITY']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $last_event = $event; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
```

There is a `$last_event` variable which is going to hold every event that has passed through `foreach`. There is an `if` statement in loop which determines that if the `$last_event` has the same date as current event in the row. If yes, then it'll pass without printing the date, and if no, then it'll print it. Before loop gets ended, there is an assignment for `$last_event` which assigns current passed event for next determination. This is the most simplest form that I could explain.

Now, if you don't want to guess similar dates in terms of just printing them out, that's another scenario.

Comment: Thanks but I'm already able to sort my array by date of event so its in the right order. The thing is that I need to find out the trick to output it to my template so that it has different row for the beginning of the month. It needs to loop trough events and I suppose check if the month data for this particular month has been already printed out. Any clue how to do that?

Comment: Then check the HTML part. If they're in the same order you can track the date of last printed event and then check it next time with the new event in the loop. Whenever they're not the same, you have a new date.

Comment: I need exactly what you described in the content above, but Im not getting desired output. Hope you could give me a clue how to determine if date has been already printed, then print only events without imprinting date to them